# if optimization at compile time

Tags: c, function, optimization, compilation

I want to know if the compiler optimize C functions for which the parameters are know at compile time?

For example, in the code below, as one of the parameters of the OR (`||`) function is known to be true, than the condition of the `if` function will always be `true`. Would it be automatically optimized? Can it be generalized to all C functions?

```
#define COND 1
int main(void)
{
    if(rand()%8<7 || COND)
        /*something*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, bvut you actually asks "How does compiler optimisation work". This is likely the broadest and most complicated field in compiler design. Not only it depends on the compiler but also the target architecture. The whole area is called "compiler construction" and I strongly recommend you search for this yourself. There are tons of documents to be found.

Answer (score 2):

A compiler *can* optimize the if statement in your code since the condition is always going to be true. This is allowed the *as-if* rule. But whether this is done or not depends on the compiler and its optimization level.

Answer (score 2):

A C compiler **cannot** optimise out `rand() % 8 < 7` since calling `rand()` has a side-effect: namely the internal *seed* is mutated.

Obviously, the shortcutting property of `||` means that `rand()` will not be called in the case `if (1 || rand())` but that's a well-defined property of the language and not a choice the compiler makes on its own initiative.

A compiler may well optimise out functions without side effects, especially those defined in the C standard library.

Comment: Useful to notice that programmers can hint compiler about the absense of side effects to encourage such optimizations. http://ideone.com/iEWTal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, optimizers do remove branches of the code that they know will never be taken. Anyway, the depth of static analysis will vary from compiler to compiler.

I doubt that current compilers do infer upper/lower bounds on "complex" arithmetic expressions like the one you mention in order to hardcode the comparison result.